# How to rebalance a portfolio in a taxable account

Tags: united-states, taxes, etf, capital-gains-tax

I hold ETFs in a regular brokerage fund that is not tax shielded. I have about 20,000$ in VT, 6,500$ of that is profit. I wanted to swap VT with VEU. Are there any financial instruments that I could use to swap one security with another in my portfolio? I don't want to sell VT and buy VEU.

Are there options or swaps or anything like that I could use to do this VT -> VEU conversion?

Are there any exchanges where I can barter shares of one company for shares of another company?

Edit: I live in the United States, this question is for US tax laws.

Comment: As far as I know, this is impossible for the average investor. The kind of people that have access to what you are talking about have millions/billions in assets that they manage for their rich clients.

Comment: @rhavelka, that's not remotely close to reality.  Trading is taxable.

Comment: @quid what exchanges do you know of that you can trade stock for stock without converting anything to cash?

Comment: Nowhere, that's MY point.  It doesn't matter if you're "rich."  When you want to trade in a non-tax-preferred account, it's a sell then buy transaction, which is subject to tax even if you have a lot of money.

Comment: How do ETF providers rebalance their portfolios? When a stock gets kicked out of an Index fund, they must be paying a lot of money in capital gains taxes to dispose off the shares of that stock no? How do they handle it?

Comment: @quid swaps and other instruments can be use to "convert" returns in one instrument to returns in another, without trading (and immediate tax consequences)

Comment: @Aditya Your question about how an ETF sells an underlying asset A without capital gains tax is *excellent*, and the answer is extremely complicated and clever. Let's say an ETF wishes to sell some of its holdings in asset A to an investment bank. (1) The investment bank buys a basket of shares of *all* the underlying assets in the ETF. (2) It gives the basket to the ETF, in exchange for shares of the ETF. (3) A couple days later, it redeems the shares of the ETF, in exchange for *only* shares of asset A. Note that all three steps are tax free.

Comment: See https://www.bloomberg.com/opinion/articles/2019-03-29/deals-on-the-train-are-everyone-s-business (scroll down to the section titled "Heartbeat"; there's a paragraph about the "advanced" explanation). The ETF can only accept redemptions of at least zillions of dollars, so you won't be able to pull off the same trick that the investment bank can.

Comment: @DStanley, sure, you can do things to trade your risk, which will have their own tax consequences, in order to not-trade your existing assets which would avoid the potential immediate tax consequences of trading.  I wouldn't equate that to trading with no taxes because you're rich.

Comment: @quid But I think that's what rhavelka is saying, that the _mechanisms_ to defer taxes (swaps, etc.) that the OP mentions are not available to smaller, retail investors, not that the rich can make the same trades without tax consequence. Eventually the tax man comes for everyone.

Comment: @quid I was a little too vague in my first comment about what I was trying to say, I was talking about trading one ticker for another (as seen in my second comment). I was going off of `"Are there any financial instruments that I could use to swap one security with another in my portfolio"` and not the tax implications of it. I don't know what (if any) tax benefits there are for trading one ticker for another, but I do know that the common person does not have access to it.

Comment: @DStanley Again, sure, but I don't see how that's relevant when the person asking the question wants to actually trade one thing for another thing, which is taxable.  The person isn't asking, is there a way for me to trade my future returns on thing A with the future returns of thing B and pay for that privilege along the way.  Even if a small enough swap were available at the retail level the answers here would probably talk this person out of using one because it's a lot more complicated.

Comment: "I wanted to swap VT with VEU"... "I don't want to sell VT and buy VEU" The term "swap" is used differently here but a swap instrument can be used to _effectively_ swap one instrument for another (hence the name).

Comment: Ok this isn't going anywhere.  There's no mythical exchange for rich people where I can trade securities without tax consequences.  I know the question uses the word swap (probably because in this person's 401k that option exists), and now you're adding effectively because it doesn't actually exist because trading is taxable, unless you're in a tax-preferred environment.

Comment: It's not a mythical exchange - it's an actual financial instrument.  Look up "equity swap" - If I own 1 million shares of MSFT and want to "exchange" it for TLSA I can do an equity swap, which "effectively" gives me cash flows equivalent to owning TLSA instead of MSFT. And with no immediate tax consequences.  I'm refuting your comment that "that's not remotely close to reality" by saying that there _are_ ways to "swap" without tax consequences, but they're not available to retail investors. But I agree that this isn't going anywhere :)

Comment: I already agreed equity swap contracts exist.  :)  You might want to re-read the followup comment from the person I was responding to `what exchanges do you know of that you can trade stock for stock without converting anything to cash?`  And, no, there is no exchange like that; and effectively trading something isn't the same as actually trading something.  AND, further, IF these contracts existed at retail, the comments would be about that they're too expensive and exist to enrich the person selling it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You can't "exchange" one asset for another similar asset, if the asset you hold is a stock.**

If you instead wanted to do this for investment real property (not a residence) or a business, you'd possibly be able to pull off a 1031 exchange (a "like-kind" exchange). Even this is very complicated (I don't have experience with it).

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to avoid short-term capital gains tax you could

- buy a put + sell a call on VT (same strike/maturity, i.e. a [synthetic forward](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/synthetic-forward-contract.asp)) and
- buy a call (+ sell a put or put spread, if your option agreement/risk tolerance allows) on VEU

with maturity dates far enough in the future that you'll have held your VT position for over a year.

The main risk is that you might get assigned early on the short call on VT and that the premium of the shorts might not cover the cost of the longs.

If you decide to sell puts, you'll also need to maintain sufficient margin on those.

---

With VT @ 101.41/sh and VEU @ 62.60/sh you'll need to sell two contracts on VT and buy three contracts on VEU (if you have some extra cash, you can buy the missing 19 shares outright)